# Fixme package fxnote background

Tags: fixme

Just a quick question. Is it possible to change the background colour for a note?

This is how I setup fixme

```
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{
    status=draft,
    author=,
    layout=inline, % also try footnote or pdfnote
    theme=color
}
\definecolor{fxnote}{rgb}{0.8000,0.0000,0.0000}
```

And now I want to set the background color to blue for instance.

TA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% provides \colorlet
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{
    status=draft,
    author=,
    layout=inline,
    theme=color
}

\definecolor{fxnote}{rgb}{0.8000,0.0000,0.0000}
% define the background colour:
\colorlet{fxnotebg}{yellow}

% refedine the layout macro:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutInline[3]{%
  \@fxdocolon {#3}{%
    \@fxuseface {inline}%
    \colorbox{fx#1bg}{\color {fx#1}\ignorespaces #3\@fxcolon #2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text \fxnote{other text} \fxnote*{blub}{blah}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Here is a version that uses `\hl` from the [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% provides \colorlet
\usepackage{soul}% provides \hl

\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{
    status=draft,
    author=,
    layout=inline,
    theme=color
}

\definecolor{fxnote}{rgb}{0.8000,0.0000,0.0000}
% define the background colour:
\colorlet{fxnotebg}{yellow}

% refedine the layout macro:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutInline[3]{%
  \@fxdocolon {#3}{%
    \@fxuseface {inline}%
    \begingroup
      \sethlcolor{fx#1bg}%
      \color {fx#1}\ignorespaces \hl{#3\@fxcolon #2}%
    \endgroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text \fxnote{other text} \fxnote*{blub}{blah}

Some Text \fxnote{A somewhat longer note that is long enough to break into the next line
for demonstration purposes} and some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I works but only if the text is short. If you put text to more than linewidth it does not wrap. I was trying to use \hl but don't know how

Comment: I have solve it with \hl I thought i was not going to be able.`\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutInline[3]{%
  \@fxdocolon {#3}{%
    \@fxuseface {inline}%
    \sethlcolor{fx#1bg}{\color {fx#1}\hl{\ignorespaces #3\@fxcolon #2}}}}
\makeatother
` I have to thank you for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately I get `Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.` with the `soul`-based solution (without `author=`)