# Package FiXme doesn't produce output

Tags: fixme

I am using `fixme` for the first time. After reading the pkg documentation and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68570/117274), I was expecting the package to output something of the PDF page, but it doesn't. The only thing I see is "some thing" and the page number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fixme}

\begin{document}
    some thing\fxnote{fix me please}

    \listoffixmes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at §3.4 Controlling the behavior of FiXme of the manual. Try with `\usepackage[draft]{fixme}`.

Comment: @moewe found it. "By default, FiXme is in final mode (LATEX itself behaves that way)."

Comment: @moewe right, that would work, too, though I used `\fxsetup{status=draft}` instead, but they both do the same as per documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on moewe's comment to the question

---

As it is stated in the documentation in § 3.4, "By default, FiXme is in final mode (LATEX itself behaves that way).", this is why we need to tell FiXme to go into draft mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{status=draft} % <====== add this line

\begin{document}
    some thing \fxnote{fix me please}

    \listoffixmes
\end{document}
```